Is there a way to use caller identity to connect database and fallback to default username/password if no caller?
When I used old JBoss AS, I was able to configure datasource to use security-domain backed with CallerIdentityLoginModule so remote user can connect to database with his username and password. Also, CallerIdentityLoginModule defines username and password which used if there no real user, for example when running EJB scheduled methods.
When using Wildfly (26.1.3 for now) and Elytron I can't determine a way to configure same behaviour. To use caller identity I can specify authentication-context for datasource which backed by authentication-configuration and security-domain used for authentication. It works for remote users, but not for EJB scheduled methods.
If I specify username and password for datasource — I can't specify authentication-context and vice versa.
May be there is a way to specify default credentials in authentication-configuration or security-domain, but I can't figure it.

I forked elytron on github and made small changes to use configured authentication name and credential if no credentials from security domain.
